# Как повернуть объект на 90 градусов при входе в другой объект? Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь повернуть контейнер на другую ленту при помощи куба внутри "сортировщика". Посмотрел всевозможные статьи и видео, ни один из примеров не помог. На данный момент остановился на этом:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
      //col.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)
        col.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);

    }
```

[image: Данный куб должен разворачивать движущийся спереди контейнер влево]

Answer (score 0):

За поворот объекта отвечает [`transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html), соответственно:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    col.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);
}
```